# Get Link To A Drill Down Report In the Google Analytics Web UI

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get a link to a drill down report for the search key word dimension  (for example if I have a dimension called search word and another dimension called Exit page under it, I'm trying to get the link to the page which contains all the exit pages where the particular word was searched ) and display the link in a table created via google visualization Table.

In the screen shots attached, if I click on the search word "coder" link on the google analytics site, then I go into the page which displays the exit pages where the coder word was searched. I want to know if there's a way to get the link to the page containing the exit pages from the first page that contains the search terms ?

The Search Terms Displayed 
[Search Terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDZeQ.png)

The page I want to get the link to, once I click on a particular search term.
[Second Dimension showing the exit pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSSm3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to recreate the page with the API, if so I believe you are looking for [`ga:searchDestinationPage` dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=internal_search&jump=ga_searchdestinationpage), and you will likely want to create a filter for that particular search term [`ga:searchKeyword==coder`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=internal_search&jump=ga_searchkeyword)

Play with [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-09-14&end-date=2015-10-14&metrics=ga%3AsearchUniques%2Cga%3AavgSearchResultViews%2Cga%3AavgSearchDepth%2Cga%3ApercentSearchRefinements%2Cga%3AavgSearchDuration%2Cga%3AsearchExitRate&dimensions=ga%3AsearchAfterDestinationPage&filters=ga%3AsearchKeyword%3D%3Dstickers) until you have it returning the dimensions and metrics you are looking for.

If you are trying figure out how to deep link into Google Analytics, simply take apart the URL:

`https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#report/content-site-search-search-terms/a{ACCOUNT_ID}w{INTERNAL_WEBPROPERTY_ID}p{PROFILE_ID}/%3F_r.drilldown%3Danalytics.searchKeyword%3A{SEARCH_KEYWORD}/`

You can use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountSummariesGuide) to get the ACCOUNT_ID, INTERNAL_WEBPROPERTY_ID and the PROFILE_ID and simply populate SEARCH_KEYWORD with whatever keyword you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt ! I was definitely trying to deep link into Google Analytics and the answer you provided really helped !